# Match regex with nothing OR expression

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have this regex:

```
[create|lorem|generate|make|fake].\s+^\d|([1-9]{1,3}) ?([^s\s]+)?
```

I want to match on these three:

```
"create 5 pages" // works
"create 5" // works
"create" // doesn't match
"create " //doesn't match
```

It works perfectly on the two first, but the last two is not recognized.

### UDPATE:

I have tried to match with ".", after `create`, but that will only match like "create " or "createX", or create unexpected matches (i.e. with `.+`). How can I, after first "create" match, say:

- match a `space` or `nothing`, meaning "create", "create " and "create 10" would work?

I have tried with this regex:

```
/[create|lorem|generate|make|fake][|\s] ?([0-9]{1,3})? ?([^s\s]+)?/g
```

I have updated the fiddle here: http://regexr.com/3aa0c - I want to match on these 4 lines, but as you see, only the first three has a match:

[image: matches]

Comment: Use of the `|` to give the "or" effect requires the string to be in `()` in most regex engines.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how regex classes (`[]`) and beginning-of-string (`^`) work.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what strings you want this to match.

Comment: I have updated with more detail, thanks

Comment: No @Biffen, I think I understand them fine. I think you misunderstood my question. I have updated it to be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: @Mattias Are you quite sure? You do know then that the first class can be written as `[|acefgklmnort]`? And that the regex `\s+^` will *never* match anything? See Ryan J's answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Let's examine what you have here:

```
[create|lorem|generate|make|fake].\s+^\d|([1-9]{1,3}) ?([^s\s]+)?
```

If we break down your regex:

1. You have some words separated by `|` in `[]`, which boils down to "any single character matching anything between the `[]`
2. followed by a single character (`.`)
3. followed by 1 or more whitespace characters (`\s+`)
4. followed by a string-begin anchor (`^`)
5. a single digit (`\d`)
6. -- or -- (`|`)
7. 1-3 digits between 1 and 9 (`[1-9]{1,3}`)
8. zero or one space (`?`)
9. followed lastly by a capture group of one or more characters NOT in the class of the literal character `s` or whitespace, repeated zero or one time (`([^s\s]+)?`)

First off, why your strings match/don't match:

1. "create 5 pages" // works

This works because a match was found for the #5 and for the string `page`. 5 is a single digit preceded by at least one whitespace, and forms the beginning of a string. The word `page` matches because those characters are not in the class of `s` or whitespace.

2. "create 5" // works

Same as above, but only for the number `5`

3. "create" // doesn't match
4. "create " //doesn't match

Neither of these match because of the fact that you have the character class/alternation construct incorrect (`(|)` vs `[]`). Second, you have a begin-string anchor in the middle of your string, which will preclude anything that appears before the beginning of the line from being matched.

If you want to match several words in alternation, you would construct the regex like so:

```
(create|lorem|generate|make|fake)
```

There's many possibilities for a regex that will correctly match what your example strings show, but without some sort of clarification on what kinds of strings you want to match/not match, we can't help further...

Hopefully this helps you understand what you have (and why it doesn't work), so you can start moving toward what I think you want.

**EDIT**
Based on new information added to the question, here's a regex that will match "any of `create`, `lorem`, `generate`, `make`, or `fake` followed by a line terminator (`$`) *or* a space followed 0-3 digits. It will *not* match page(s) or anything following the digits. If you want it to, suggest you modify the regex to explicitly capture your words, and not use the `[^s\s]` character class.

```
(create|lorem|generate|make|fake)(\s[0-9]{0,3}|$)
```

Matches:

```
"create 10 pages"
"create 10"
"create "
"create"
```

but not:

```
"createX"
```

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/mI7cG3/1)

Comment: Thanks for a very learning answer, @Ryan J, I have updated my initial question.

Comment: @Mattias I've added an edit. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: `([0-9]{1,3})?` can be shortened to `[0-9]{0,3}`.

Comment: @Biffen ahh yes, I'm not sure why I missed that.